# How to fit the HTML content to the web browser in Windows Phone 7

Tags: javascript, c#, html, windows-phone-7

I am trying to resize the browser with the size of html content. I have try with following code.

```
private void WebBrowser_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    String htmlHead = "<html><head><meta charset='UTF-8'/><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width='480', initial-scale='1'\"/>{0}</head><body onload=\"ResizeWebBrowser()\"><center>{1}</center></body></html>";
    myWebView.NavigateToString(String.Format(htmlHead, getScript(), getHTMLContent()));
    myWebView.IsScriptEnabled = true;
    myWebView.ScriptNotify += new EventHandler<NotifyEventArgs>(WebBrowser_ScriptNotify);
}

private void WebBrowser_ScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Value) && !(e.Value == ""))
    {
        this.myWebView.Height = double.Parse(JsonParsing(e.Value));
        myWebView.UpdateLayout();
    }
}

private string getScript()
{
    string script = "<script>";
    script += "function ResizeWebBrowser()";
    script += "{";
    script += "var _renderedHeight=document.body.firstChild.offsetHeight * 0.66;";
    script += "var _json = '{\"rendered_height\" : '+_renderedHeight+'}';";
    script += "window.external.notify(_json)";
    script += "}";
    script += "ResizeWebBrowser();";
    script += "</script>";
    return script;
}

public string getHTMLContent()
{
    StringBuilder htmlBody = new StringBuilder();
    htmlBody.Append("<table cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" width=\"704\" height=\"484\" background=\"https://known.com/img/back/123456.jpg\" style=\"background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center;\">");
    htmlBody.Append("<tr>");
    htmlBody.Append("<td valign=top>");
    htmlBody.Append("<div style=\"position: absolute;\">");
    htmlBody.Append("<div style=\"position: absolute; display: table; width: 132px; height: 132px; top: 44px; left: 44px; z-index:0;\">");
    htmlBody.Append("<img src=\"https://known.com/img/icon/87654.jpg\" width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\"/>");
    htmlBody.Append("</div>");
    htmlBody.Append("<div style=\"position: absolute; display: table; width: 704px; height: 484px; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index:0; \">");
    htmlBody.Append("<img src=\"https://known.com/img/icon/234255.jpg\" width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\"/>");
    htmlBody.Append("</div>");
    htmlBody.Append("<div style=\"position: absolute; display: table; width: 440px; height: 264px; top: 184px; left: 184px; z-index:0;  font-family:times;  font-size:14px;  color:#FFFFFF; \" align=\"center\">");
    htmlBody.Append("<div style=\"display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;\">");
    htmlBody.Append("</div>");
    htmlBody.Append("</div>");
    htmlBody.Append("</div>");
    htmlBody.Append("</td>");
    htmlBody.Append("</tr>");
    htmlBody.Append("</table>");
    return htmlBody.ToString();
}
```

Now I can resize the browser. But now I am facing one problem. 
That is, the content is exceed from the browser. If I double click the page, then only the the content become to fit to the browser. 
Please let me know any way to fit the content to the browser.

[Please click here to get my sample project](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=9CBE7976CDD57B70!209&authkey=!AB-OiBfrDGf14UU&ithint=file%2Czip)

Comment: Please explain your issue better with some screenshots

Comment: Hi @csharpwinphonexaml.. I have attached my sample project. Please download it and let me any way to resolve my problem.